# Sharepoint 2013: Displaying a List View Web Part in Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt

I am trying to do an accordion with the text/description and then opening up into a list view web part (XSLT).  The accordion expands/collapses fine.  The issue is that the list is not showing when I expand.  The XSLT is not rendering.  The list view web part is already on the page but it will not display inside of the accordion.  I am using the code below:

```
<!doctype html>`
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Collapse content</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true
    });
  });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="accordion">
      <h3>Text<br><p>Click for more details.</p></br></h3>
      <div>XSLT WebPart</div>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```